# Parametrization of a light-like line

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, special-relativity

I would like to learn how to count the number of parameters in a light-like trajectory in Minkowski space.

Naively, I would write

$$
x^{\mu}(t) = x_{0}^{\mu} + t \, p^{\mu}
$$

and consider that $p^{2} = 0$. This leads me to count:

- d independent parameters for $x_{0}^{\mu}$;
- d-1 independent parameters for $p^{\mu}$ since the constraint $p^{2} =0$
  removes one component.

In $d=4$ this gives a total of 7 independent numbers. But the right answer is $5$. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Adding something proportional to $p^\mu$ to $x_0^\mu$ gives the same trajectory. What you should do is pick $x_0^\mu$ from the orthogonal complement to $p^\mu$, which reduces the dimensions by one to six. I don't know how you'd get five, though.

Comment: Thank you @Javier ! Your answer made me get it right. In this specific case, the next degree of freedom is removed by the scaling of $p$. The vectors $p$ and $\lambda p$ generate the same line (for real $\lambda$). Also the constraint $p^{2} =0$ does not see scaling, so indeed scale is another independent freedom. Finally, in $d$ dimensions, one has $2d - 3$ parameters.